# Record the Application session time using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, nstimer, performance

I want to record the duration of Application executed in order to keep logs of activity of users. Should I use a global NSTimer to record the time? or is there any better method?

Sample codes are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you record the current time when your application starts in the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method and then record the end time and log it in the applicationWillTerminate: method?